# How to restart drawing a line in HTML5 canvas with a gradient

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, line, gradient

I've got a many lines with gradients in them drawn in canvas, I'm drawing it like so, there's a js fiddle link too.

http://jsfiddle.net/mailrox/XWLgD/2/

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('c');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

context.fillStyle = "rgb(255, 255, 255)";

//draw lines
for (i=1;i<canvas.height;i++){
    if(i%100 == 0){

        //a line
       // linear gradient from start to end of line
       var grad= context.createLinearGradient(50, 50, 150, 150);
       grad.addColorStop(0, "red");
       grad.addColorStop(1, "green");

       context.strokeStyle = grad;
       context.beginPath();
       //line start point
       context.moveTo(0, (i + 20 + 0.5));
       //line end point
       context.lineTo(canvas.width, (i + 20 + 0.5) );

       context.stroke();

       context.closePath();

    }
}
```

The problem is each loop I'm restarting the gradient however the gradient only seems to be going across all the lines. If you take a look at the link it's pretty obvious but hard to explain.

What I'd like to happen is each line has it's own green to red gradient opposed to the gradient going across all them. Is there something special I'm missing to restart the line or gradient.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your gradient went downwards with 45 degrees.
Imagine your gradient going over the complete area just being visible there, where you are drawing a line.

I changed your code from this:

```
//Create a gradient groing from point (50,50) to (150,150)
var grad= context.createLinearGradient(50, 50, 150, 150);
```

to this:

```
//Create a gradient groing from point (50,50) to (150,50)
var grad= context.createLinearGradient(50, 50, 150, 50);
```

Check this out:

http://jsfiddle.net/XWLgD/3/

PS: I changed the lineWidth to highlight the gradient effect :P

---

You can even shorten and speed up your code by putting gradient creation and drawing outside of your loop:

http://jsfiddle.net/XWLgD/4/